# Visual Studio debug break on floating point register change

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, visual-studio-debugging, x87

Is there a way in Visual Studio (2012\13\15, preferably in 2015) to add a debug condition to break when the `STAT` register changes?

I'm referring to the register value of `STAT` which can be viewed by opening the "Register" window while debugging, right clicking that window and choosing "Floating Point" [x87 and SSE Floating Point Assists in IA-32: Flush-To-Zero (FTZ) and Denormals-Are-Zero (DAZ)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/x87-and-sse-floating-point-assists-in-ia-32-flush-to-zero-ftz-and-denormals-are-zero-daz):

[image: STAT Floating Point register]
I know you can break on registers like `CS` or `EAX` but I doesn't seem to work by simply changing `EAX` to `STAT`.

Comment: Interesting question.  I don't remember x87 very well, but I think STAT isn't a full register, just part of the FP status register, which also contains other bits that will change frequently.  Of course, the debugger has to single-step anyway to do this, and it can just mask `STAT` out of wherever it comes from.  It should be possible for a debugger to have this feature, but I can't say anything about whether Visual Studio actually *does* allow it.

Comment: Do you know what is the name of that register?

Comment: oh nvm, I had that wrong.  The FPU status word and FPU control word are separate registers, accessed with [FSTSW](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FSTSW:FNSTSW.html) and [FSTCW](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FSTCW:FNSTCW.html) respectively.  The article you linked documents how to use FSTCW to modify and reload the control word. Using FSTSW for the status word is identical.  (Of course a debugger will look at saved values in memory after the OS's context-switch handler saves state after a single-step or breakpoint, so it's actually the context switch that runs FSTSW to save the status word)

Comment: I guess I was thinking of the MXCSR (for SSE math), where the FP exception bits are in the same register as the control bits (again, see that article you linked).

Comment: If its one of the exception flags of the FPU status register you're interested in you can unmask that exception in the FPU control word. When that exception bit becomes set the CPU will generate an FPU exception which the OS should turn in to a SEH exception and you'll get a "first chance exception" in the debugger. However, I'm not sure how easily you can continue from that exception as if the exception wasn't unmasked. Also note that most FPU instructions will change the STAT register, since it contains the FPU's top of stack pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I eventually found the location that triggered that flag using a binary search on the code by placing regular break points and narrowing it down. I failed to find a way to break when the STAT word is changed...

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's a way to do it directly because the Visual Studio Debugger doesn't recognize those register names as valid register names for use, just in the display window.  However, you can do it in a round-about way by injecting some assembly to inspect the value at any point (and you can create a macro for this and use it wherever you need): short this_ax, last_ax; _asm { push eax; fstsw ax; mov this_ax,ax; mov last_ax,ax; pop eax; }, and then add a conditional breakpoint on "mov last_ax,ax" which tests if last_ax != this_ax.

Comment: @RickC.Hodgin , I already solved that issue but your comment seems to include a solution, perhaps you should post it as an answer to the question for future comers